# Permissions problem with dual-boot Linux/Windows

Tags: permissions, dual-boot

I have a dual boot Linux/Windows system with the two systems
sitting on entirely separate physical hard-drives
(yes, it *is* that old).
On the Linux system, there is a sub-directory
in `/media/myusername` called `windrive`.
I mount the Windows partition using:

> sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0000 /dev/sda2 /media/myusername/windrive

so that I end up with the Linux system mounted on `/dev/sdb1`
and the Windows partition mounted on `dev/sda2`.

Most read/write operations on the Windows partition work OK
but a few do  not.
For example (and please note, **this is only an example**),
I can copy the file `nameOfFile.txt` from my Linux desktop
to my Windows desktop using:

> cp ~/Desktop/nameOfFile.txt /media/myusername/windrive/Users/myusername/Desktop

However, moving the file only partly succeeds because of a problem with permissions. Specifically,

> mv ~/Desktop/nameOfFile.txt /media/myusername/windrive/Users/myusername/Desktop

results in the error:

> mv: preserving times for '/media/myusername/windrive/Users/myusername/Desktop/nameOfFile.txt': Operation not permitted

As a one-off solution, I can simply use `sudo mv` instead of `mv` ... but is there a way of mounting the Windows partition so that this problem does not arise at all?

As a follow on, if this is possible and I do it, are
there any significant risks involved?

***Added:*** I am specifically interested in *a general way of overcoming* the issue about preserving times. I have used `cp` and `mv` merely as illustrations of what does, and does not work. The problem arises whenever I have a library that is on the Windows partition and shared between a Linux and Windows app.

Comment: You can use `cp -p` and preserve times (but if your Linux filesystem supports `creation time` then the file you copy will no  longer have `creation time` in the NTFS partition)

Comment: Btw, since you are moving a file between different filesystems then what the command `mv` does is to copy the file to the destination (NTFS partition) and remove the file from the original filesystem (basically `cp` and `rm`). Thus `mv` here is no longer neccesary.

Comment: Unfortunately ... (a) `cp -p` fails for exactly the same reason as the example I gave with `mv`. (b) it's worth adding (even though `mv` and `cp` are not my main focus) that `mv` does not work as you suggest. The copy proceeds OK but because of the error with setting the time, `mv` exits with a failure and does not remove the original file. But in any case, as my added note explains, I'm interested in a general solution to the permissions problem.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have that behavior (maybe the versions of our commands or ntfs driver are different). Becuase I actually got the same behavior than you: `mv: preserving times: Operation not permitted`.  When I use `mv`  the file is `moved` (copied and removed) although I got that error.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you. If you post that as an answer and delete your comment, I will mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don't care about *preserving times* or *permissions*  and want to avoid the error message: `Operation not permitted` when using `mv` (as well as to avoid using `sudo`) you need to mount the drive specifying a user (and agroup if you want) by using `uid` and `gid` in the `mount` options:

```bash
sudo mount -t ntfs -o nls=utf8,umask=0000,uid=1000,gid=1000 /dev/sda2 /media/myusername/windrive
```

Where `uid=1000` and `gid=1000` might be different according yo your needs.